# What is causing the ActionMailer error: undefined local variable or method `jp2CharContext'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, actionmailer, nameerror

When attempting to do character detection on incoming emails, sometimes a `NameError` is thrown with this error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `jp2CharContext' for #<CharDet::SJISContextAnalysis:0x2abb2b2a8bc0>
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in rchardet 1.3 which has been fixed in 1.3.1.

`lib/rchardet/jpcntx.rb` is referring to `jp2CharContext`, but since `jp2CharContext` is defined at the module level, it needs to have an upcase name to be in scope.

In 1.3.1 the variable has been renamed from `jp2CharContext` to `JP2_CHAR_CONTEXT`.

See also: [rchardet RubyDoc page](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rchardet/1.3.1/frames)